# Retrieving xml value into a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

In the following XML structure how do i retrieve the name value and put this into a string?
(i am using a XPathNavigator in my method)

```
<testsystem>
    <test>
       <name>one</name>
       <name>two</name>
       <name>three</name>
    </test>
</testsystem>
```

The name will get displayed in the boundcolumn of a datagrid.

I was able to get a attribute with a syntax alike this: (but when changing the xml struture it no longer holds a attribute value)

```
string name = nav.GetAttribute("name", "")
```

But have no luck getting the value with a nav as of yet.

The purpose is to be able to use it for the following object so i can put name into it.

```
test t = new test() { Name = name, Questions= new List<Questions>() };
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiple `name` nodes you could use this approach:

```
XPathNodeIterator iter = xml.CreateNavigator().Select("//test/name");
while (iter.MoveNext())
{
    var nav = iter.Current;
    string name = nav.Value;
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Alternately you could use the [`XmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dc0c9ekk.aspx):

```
var nodeList = xml.GetElementsByTagName("name");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: forgot to mention i am using a Xpath navigator, edited in in the main post :)

Comment: @DelvinK see if my edit helps. If not please share how your XPath expression looks like.

Comment: Cheers, but there remains just one problem. Because in my list i have several names and it shows the first one all the time insteed for example one, two, three etc..(updated in first question) Although when i had the name as a attribute it showed all my names as: one, two, three, now i only get one one one as result

Comment: Thanks! i managed to get what i wanted with the following expresion: string name = nav.Select("/testsystem//test/name").Current.ToString();

Comment: @DelvinK great! You should probably use `"/testsystem/test/name"` (notice no double `//`). That way the path to the `name` nodes is specific. The double `//` works but it is used to find the nodes no matter where they occur. I was using it to avoid specifying the root, although being explicit is good practice.

Answer (score 1):

For example, create an XmlDocument, load the string into it with the LoadXml method, and then document.GetElementsByTagName("name")[0].InnerText will provide the value. There may be better ways to deal with XML if we knew how complex your XML structure actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the XPathNavigator is positioned on the element you want, than `nav.Value` will return the string value. See [XPathItem.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathitem.value.aspx).

Comment: do i position it with nav.SelectSingleNode and then later get the value or?

Comment: You can position it in many ways, yes SelectSingleNode would be one way. And then once it is positioned get the value.